# JS Datepicker Format

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have purchased a template which comes with a date-picker.

However I cannot change the format, its currently showing the date as `MM/DD/YYYY hh:ii` I want to change this to `DD-MM-YYYY` (no time).

Here is the date picker:

```
<div id="minimum-dtpicker" class="input-group date">
<input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="ti-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

And here is part of the `datepicker.js` script

```
$('#minimum-dtpicker').datetimepicker({
     format : "DD-MM-YYYY",
    locale: 'en-gb'
            });
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Use just **datepicker** than **datetimepicker**

Comment: Changing `.datetimepicker(` to `.datepicker(` hasn't change anything?

Comment: Both are different libraries...

Comment: which library actually are you using?

Comment: There isn't a datepicker library

Comment: @PranavCBalan - Its this one http://momentjs.com/ I think but as I say I purchased a template that came with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is using momentjs, you are able to specify the format as follows in their [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```
moment(<unformatted date goes here>).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```